# Sorting a string numerically in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I have a column in a table that is populated with a string

```
level 1, level 2, level 3 ... level 12.
```

I wish to order by this column but not alphabetically as this orders the column

```
1 10 11 12 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

How can I order this column to be in correct numerical order despite it being a string type?

I imagine I have to extract only the numerical component of the string and cast it to an `int` but I don't know how to do this in SQL Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select *
From YourTable
Order by CAST( SUBSTRING(YourColumn, 6,LEN(YourColumn)) AS Int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      TableName
ORDER BY  CAST(REPLACE(ColumnName, 'level', '') AS INT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT col
FROM
  (values('level 1'),('level 2'),('level 3'),
  ('level 5'),('level 8'),('level 10'),('level 12')) 
    x(col)
ORDER BY stuff(col, 1,6, '') + 0
```

The stuff will remove the first 6 characters, the +0 will cast the rest of the col as integer(which can also be done with cast or convert)